# Routing 'fake' sub sub posts

Tags: permalinks

I currently have these custom permalink rules:

/%category%/%postname%/

I'd like /%category%/%postname%/%sometext% to display the same as /%category%/%postname%/ - from there, I will either use PHP or jQuery to display different content on the page.

EG:

/about-us/team/mike to display the /about-us/team page, and then I'll highlight 'Mike's bio' with jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: This is functionally identical to the use of # and IDs to auto navigate to places on a page, what you're trying to do sounds terribly like a kludge/work around. Why do you wish to do this?

Comment: Mainly for SEO purposes.

Comment: If it helps, this is pretty much exactly what I want to achieve: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/url-rewrite-for-query-in-url?replies=6

Comment: hmmm I'm doubtful that this will be of any use SEO wise, especially since correct use of canonical urls in the head tags will mean that google will ignore these additional pages, that or it will penalise you for duplicated content

Comment: Yeah, I know it is a bit of a cludge. All I want to do is wordpress to 'ignore' anything after the www.sitename.com/%category%/%postname% - so I can process it on page.

Comment: Could you not use actual sub pages, and give them a parent page which is the same but without the highlighting? As far as I can tell this would be detrimental to SEO and a faff at that, I see no benefit to doing thing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7109/discussion-between-martin-alderson-and-tom-j-nowell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to whitelist a new query_var:

```
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "subpage"; // represents the name of the product category as shown in the URL
    return $aVars;
}

// hook add_query_vars function into query_vars
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

You will need then need a rewrite rule to match your URL and pass in the correct query variables:

```
add_rewrite_rule('([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?','index.php?pagename=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&subpage=$matches[3]','top');
```

Finally on your pages template, you'll want to look for that query var, e.g.

```
if( !empty(get_query_var('subpage') )){ 
    // do subpage stuff
    $subpage = get_query_var('subpage');
    // process above value
} else { 
    // not on subpage, do normal page stuff 
}
```

Flush permalinks and you're good to go.

You should probably make good use of get_template_part, how you store the subpage data is up to you, post meta might work, just remember that it won't be searchable by default but there are other questions that can answer that problem